# Docusign API - Setting margins for HTML documents

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on integrating a PHP app with the DocuSign REST API. I'm creating new documents from HTML, similar to document 1 in the example [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email). The structure comes through just fine, but the margins on the resulting document are way too wide for my purposes, and I can't find a way to set them to a custom value. It seems to ignore the margins on my HTML body and just set it to a default of 1 inch.

Normally if you create a document using a pdf for example, the custom margins on the pdf would be used, so it seems like there should be some way to do this for HTML. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a negative value for the outermost div's margin value. Eg

```
<div style="margin:-2em;">
    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me in HTML non-responsive mode.