# Can't get rid of the margin around HTML document

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Responsive Signing and I have a HTML document starting the DOM tree like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; padding: 0px; background-color: pink; color: #11263c;">
      My content goes here!
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried setting the margin and padding to 0px. I saw some other SO questions related that suggested doing negative values like -2em but still had no success on that.

Any other suggestions? Is this by design? Any way around it? I want my HTML to take up the entire height and width of the document. Thanks.

EDIT:
I would like the pink area (representing my content) to stretch to the bounds of the document.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kazo.png)

Comment: Do you mean margins on the final document PDF?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @InbarGazit On both the DocuSign view and the exported PDF from that view. I will try to update my post with an image. Thank you.

Comment: The image indicates you're not using HTML (responsive) signing. This image is of regular PDF signing.

Comment: Thanks Inbar for your response. I am modifying example 38 "Responsive Signing" of the Node.js Quickstart repo, so I assumed it was using the correct signing type.  I will continue to investigate why its not using the Responsive Signing. My guess, I haven't added in any special tabs like <ds-signature /> yet (and I will, still building other parts of my template) so maybe it automatically shows me the regular PDF signing until I add something that requires responsive-ness?

Comment: Setting a negative margin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151269/docusign-api-setting-margins-for-html-documents) when sending HTML in non-responsive mode seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently an option with DocuSign. The PDF has fixed width that cannot currently be modified, even if you use HTML for sending.